# Using $.ajax to return HTML & turn it into JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

```
var urlArray = window.location.pathname.split("/"),
    idFromUrl = urlArray[2],
    dataPath = "/bulletins/" + idFromUrl + "/data";

$.ajax({
    url: dataPath,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        var dataObj = data.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');

        console.log(dataObj);
    }
});
```

I'm grabbing the contents of an HTML page, and the contents on that page is super simple. It's just an "array", although it's plain text so when it returns, JavaScript is treating it as a string instead of an array. This is all that's on that HTML page:

```
[{"sermontitle":"test","welcome":"test","_id":"52e7f0a15f85b214f1000001"}]
```

Without replace the `&quot;`'s, a `console.log` spits out `[{&quot;sermontitle&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;welcome&quot;:&quot;test&quot;,&quot;_id&quot;:&quot;52e7f0a15f85b214f1000001&quot;}]`

So my question is, how can I turn that HTML string (that's already in "array" form) into an actual array?

Comment: Why the response are with &quot;?

Comment: How do you mean you get that from an `HTML` page? How do you have an `array`? It looks like `JSON` except the `[]`. `JSON` has a strong grammar. I would try to strip the `[]` and then `json.parse()` it.

Comment: @dollarvar I'm getting that from an HTML page, cause I'm somewhat hacking a Node view that's built with Jade to just dump all the data on an empty page. Couldn't figure out how to create a JSON file on the fly the way I can with Jade templates.

Comment: Does stripping the `[]` and then `json.parse()` it work?

Comment: json.parse does indeed work. I'd probably want to strip the `[]` still though. Do you know how to do that with a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the returned HTML fragment as JSON:

```
JSON.parse(dataObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON.parse

```
JSON.parse(dataObj);
```

Comment: i accidentally clicked delete, too bad :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change "dataType" to "json" and it will convert it for you:

```
var urlArray = window.location.pathname.split("/"),
    idFromUrl = urlArray[2],
    dataPath = "/bulletins/" + idFromUrl + "/data";

$.ajax({
    url: dataPath,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

If it is returning the `&quot;` instead of `"`, then I would change the AJAX return page to make sure it is doing a proper JSON response.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but no luck. It just returns nothing. I think it's because it's not actually a JSON file.

Comment: Have you used put in JSON headers in the file?